# Ion-color-secondary/primary class not applied

Tags: ionic-framework, stenciljs

I've created a stencil.js application (app starter) where I would like to use ionic components.

I included Ionic using the cdn following this tutorial (https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cdn). I have a problem with the style of some of the components like buttons, toggle etc. The problem is that the primary/secondary/x style is not applied also if I use

```
color="primary"
```

I've searched a lot to solve this problem and I saw that the property .ion-color-primary isn't apply to the button like it should, so none of the colors are applied to the button that remains white.

If I use Ionic from cdn in a html page (with no stencil.js) the problem don't happen so I think that the problem it's stencil.

I've the latest stencil version, 4.11.7.

Comment: Why don't you use the ionic-pwa starter? `npm init stencil ionic-pwa`. That starter project is set up to bundle the ionic components along with your app, instead of you having to load it from a CDN.

Comment: I need to have a stenciljs projects + ionic components, not a ionic pwa starter.

Comment: What happens if you use "scoped:true" instead of "shadow:true" in your stencil component? This should be in the component decorator. Does that change anything?

Comment: I just tested the CDN using vanilla HTML and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/vqs1pe9L/
Since you're using Stencil, I recommend using the [PWA Toolkit](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-pwa-toolkit) as Simon suggested, which is essentially just a Stencil app with Ionic preconfigured. I've used it many times without problems.

Comment: I solved using the pwa starter!